# How to create a custom systemctl command?

Tags: systemd, services

I created the

mycommand.target

```
[Unit]
Description=Mycom
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=systemd-mycom.service
After=systemd-mycom.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

systemd-mycom.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Mycom
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=other.target
After=other.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/my/file.sh
```

file.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
rm /etc/some/stuff
```

this is just a test command, but the actual stuff is far complex

When I tried to run the command via:

```
sudo systemctl Mycom
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown operation Mycom
```

How do I properly create a new systemctl command?

Comment: What command did you run exactly? Why do you need a new target?

Comment: Added the command

Answer (score 0):

When you use systemctl you have to use it like this, as root:

```
systemctl start # starts the service        
systemctl stop # stops the service         
systemctl enable # starts the service on start-ups        
systemctl restart # restarts the service
```

That's why you're getting unknown command error. You should use `sudo systemctl start Mycom`.

Comment: its possible to run `systemctl hibernate`